# Read a file by strings in Python

Tags: python, file, split

Hi im newbie with python and i want to read a file by strings.
The file has the following structure:

> semilla
>
> n_galleria t_espera t_llegada
>
> p_ticket t_servicio
>
> n_colosso min_colosso max_colosso
>
> n_prisionero m_prisionero miu_prisionero sigma_prisionero
>
> n_david
>
> p_decision n_orcagna miu_orcagna sigma_orcagna
>
> n_libreria p_libreria min_libreria max_libreria

until now i just have this:

```
f = open("/tmp/entrada.txt")
g = open("/tmp/salida.txt", "w+")

 for linea in f.readlines():
    line = linea.split(' ')


f.close()
g.close()
```

btw, every field at the file structure is the name of the variable. I mean, first, want to save a variable called "semilla" with the value that will be there at entrada.txt

Comment: Why are you using `linea.split('|')`? There are not `|` in your text file! Please read here: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Also, why are you using `readlines` instead of just `for linea in f:`? And why the `[-1]`, which throws away everything but the last word, when you wanted every word?

Comment: @gmas80 u'r right! please help me

Comment: `for linea in f.readlines().split(' ')` for instance? However, it is not so clear your intent.. can you explain with an example?

Comment: @gmas80 well, actually i want something that after running, store the respective values of semilla, t_espera, and thus...

Comment: Do you mean an object that has a key (`semilla`) and a list of values (`[n_galleria t_espera t_llegada]`)?

Comment: only the list of values, something like ( `[semilla, t_espera, ..., max_libreria]`) @gmas80

Comment: @IvanG4Life: this is easy! look at my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *naive* solution.. but easy to follow:

```
tokens = []    
for linea in f.readlines():
    line_content = linea.split(' ')
    for token in line_content:
        tokens.append(token)
print(tokens)
```

Comment: @IvanG4Life: did I catch your requirements? You will get `[sevilla n_galleria t_espera t_llegada... ]`

Comment: Yes!! ty buddy :) then i put semilla = tokens[0], t_llegada=tokens[1] and thus!

Answer (score 0):

If by "word" you mean you want to be able to iterate through every single substring delimited from the rest of the text by two spaces, you can do this:

```
for word in f.read().split(' '):
    do_something_to_string
```

There's no need to read the file by line if you don't actually need to parse it by line.

Answer (score 0):

For word tokenization, it is best to use the `nltk` module which will handle word separators of any kind. So you can do this:

```
import nltk

f = open("/tmp/entrada.txt").read()

# return the list of words
words = nltk.word_tokenize(f)
```

And this should be more robust for any kind of text that you have.